# Simple Java program related to hierarchical inheritance is not giving desired output

Tags: java, inheritance

I have written the following Java program:

**Tab1:**

```
package base;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter first number:  ");
    int num1 = obj.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the second number:  ");
    int num2 = obj.nextInt();

    Add obj1 = new Add();
    Mul obj2 = new Mul();

    obj1.getData(num1, num2);

    int add = obj1.addition();
    int mul = obj2.multiplication();

    System.out.println("The addition of the two numbers is:  " +add);
    System.out.println("The multiplication of the two numbers is:  " +mul);
}

}
```

**Tab2:**

```
package base;

public class Parent {

int num1, num2;

void getData(int x, int y){
    num1 = x;
    num2 = y;
}

}
```

**Tab3:**

```
package base;

public class Add extends Parent {

int addition(){
    int x;
    x = num1 + num2;
    return x;
}
}
```

**Tab4:**

```
package base;

public class Mul extends Parent {

int multiplication(){
    int x;
    x = num1*num2;
    return x;
}
}
```

When I run the code it gives me a result like this:

```
Enter first number:
5
Enter second number:
4
The addition of the two numbers is:  9
The multiplication of the two numbers is: 0
```

I have got the same type of result with all kind of different inputs.

The result of the multiplication is always 0

I have cross checked my code several times but apparently I cannot find any mistake.

Where am I going wrong?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You never used `getData()` to set the values on `obj2`.  Zero times zero is zero.  You may also find this useful: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Change the name of getData to setData please. You are setting data, so it's confusing if your function calls getData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add obj1 = new Add();
Mul obj2 = new Mul();

obj1.getData(num1, num2);
```

You created *two* distinct objects, `obj1` and `obj2` but put non-zero values only into `obj1`.  The values in `obj2` are still zero.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass argument to `Mul` instance before calling its method

```
obj2.getData(num1, num2);
int mul = obj2.multiplication();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no call to `getData()` on `obj2`:

```
obj2.getData(num1, num2);
```